# Bind a command to go to a specific symbol in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

### My issue:

I would like to bind a few keyboard shortcuts to navigate to specific symbols in my currently open file within VS Code.

### Example:

- I want to navigate to the symbol `<template>` by pressing `cmd+1`.
- I want to navigate to the symbol `<script>` by pressing `cmd+2`.
- I want to navigate to the symbol `<style>` by pressing `cmd+3`.

By default, you can do that by pressing `cmd+p` and then in the palette typing `@template` which will jump to the template tag within the open file.

So a solution might look something like this in my keybinding.json:

```
  { 
    "key": "cmd+1",
    "command": "workbench.action.gotoSymbol",
    "args": ["@template"], 
  }
```

However, the args part of this does not work. I'm wondering if anyone knows a good solution for setting up key bindings like this so I can navigate around my files with shortcuts.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem, which is pretty funny because it's an existing extension for VS Code that does exactly what I am looking for:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=andersonmfjr.vue-jumptotag

To bind the keyboard shortcuts in keybindings.json

```
  { 
    "key": "cmd+1",
    "command": "extension.jumptotemplate",
  },
  { 
    "key": "cmd+2",
    "command": "extension.jumptoscript",
  },
  { 
    "key": "cmd+3",
    "command": "extension.jumptostyle",
  },
```

That does exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
{ 
  "key": "cmd+1",
  "command": "workbench.action.quickOpen",
  "args": "@<template>", 
},
```

The command `workbench.action.gotoSymbol` won't take an argument, but `workbench.action.quickOpen` will.  I don't know why there is that difference, but as you know if you start the Quick Open Panel with `@` you get object references.  And the rest of your text `<template>` for example will automatically be entered into the input box.

It will filter for those symbols but will not jump to the first one.  If you want that additional functionality, you would have to consider a macro which would select the first entry.

---

There is an alternative that allows you to navigate to anything by using a matching regex.  See the extension [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by) which allows to jump to any string.  For example (in settings.json):

```
"selectby.regexes": {

  "goTo<template>": {
    "moveby": "<template>",
  }
}
```

and your keybinding (keybindings.json):

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+1",            // <template>`
  "command": "moveby.regex",
  "args": ["go<template>", "moveby", "next", "start", "wrap"],
  // "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == javascriptreact"
}
```

You can set it up to jump to the previous instance as well:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+alt+1",            // previous <template>
  "command": "moveby.regex",
  "args": ["goTo<template>", "moveby", "prev", "start", "wrap"],
  // "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == javascriptreact"
}
```

either way it should now "wrap", it just depends on how many `<templates>` you have in the file and which direction you want to go to first.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. This came really close but was not exactly what I needed since there's no way to use moveby to jump to previous AND next instances. I upvoted your answer anyway. I just found a pre-built extension that does exactly what I was looking for, I guess I should have searched more thoroughly in the extensions marketplace.

Comment: It is a good suggestion about the `moveby` command.  I opened an issue asking that the command wrap around the end of the file if need be.  So that only the one keybinding would be sifficient.

Comment: @thomallen: in v0.7.4 of SelectBy you can now add a `"wrap"` argument to `moveby` to try a cursor wrap around